# How to SSL-enable an intranet-only site for device access?

Tags: ssl-certificate, vpn, intranet

**Is there a way to apply a certificate from a trusted authority (e.g. godaddy) to an intranet-only site?**

I'm trying to figure out how our mobile devices can access REST endpoints on an intranet site via https://intranet-site/rest/services/service?foo=bar.

Our team uses a "Domain Certificate" issued by AcmeCA for intranet-only sites but our mobile devices on our VPN cannot access these sites -- there are certificate errors preventing access.

Our mobile devices are (presumably) using a Cisco VPN to access the site.  I'd think that would be enough since VPN effectively puts you "on the intranet" as I understand it (wherein lies the problem).

Comment: Hi @Corey, Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: No. I used a public cert.

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile devices need to trust your domain certificates, which they don't since they are not members of the domain. If you have an MDM solution there might be a way to push those certificates down, but you'll also need to configure your certificate store on your mobile devices. It would be much easier to put a public certificate on your server.

Comment: Is it possible to put a public certificate on a server that isn't accessible to the certificate authority?

Comment: I wouldn't see why not (I've never tried). When setting up the certificate you will want to disable CRL so it does not try to query the CA.

Comment: Seems like that comes with it's own set of problems. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/964.certificate-revocation-list-crl-verification-an-application-choice.aspx